# Detecting flash player - sort of working

Tags: php, javascript, flash, cookies

I'm using this to detect if flash player is installed. then if it is, I display specific fields.

```
<script>
  var hayFlash = function(a,b){try{a=new ActiveXObject(a+b+'.'+a+b)}catch(e){a=navigator.plugins[a+' '+b]}return!!a}('Shockwave','Flash')

  if(hayFlash) {
   document.cookie = 'flash=1';
  }
  else {
    alert("Flash Player is required to copy GUID's");
    document.cookie = 'flash=0';

  }
</script>
```

This seems to work.

The issue I have is once it's set the cookie, I have to refresh to page to have access to the cookie.

Is there any way to have this page check for the player, set a cookie ( or other variable ) then have the rest of the page load showing or not the correct fields ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use `hayFlash` as a global variable? set it first, use it through out the page?

Comment: Is hayflash available to php ? os I can check it's value and then display if it's set !